# Input validation with the `re` library

Tags: python, regex, validation, input

I am learning [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) input validation with the `re` library.

Currently I am using the following:

```
valid = re.match('[1-5]', UserInput)
```

I wish to make sure the input is between `1` and `5`.

There is just one problem with this method; if I input something that begins with `1-5` followed by something else (for example, 1bdfgh, 354), it is considered valid.

Is there a way around this? I would prefer the solution still using the `re` library as it is for school.

Comment: You want that input only between 1-5 ? No strings etc?

Comment: You can use `[1-5]{1}`

Comment: Why not just check if `int(UserInput) in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` will only check if the string *starts* with the pattern you give it.  To have it match the whole string, you can do:

```
valid = re.match('[1-5]$', UserInput)
```

In a Regex pattern, `$` represents the end of the string.  So, the above pattern will match strings that start with a character in the set `[1-5]` and then end.  The only strings which satisfy this condition are `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, and `'5'`.

---

Note that in Python 3.4, you can use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) for this:

```
valid = re.fullmatch('[1-5]', UserInput)
```

It is the same as `re.match`, except that it matches the whole string rather than just the start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use word boundaries

```
>>> a = '1sdv'
>>> valid = re.match('[1-5]',a)
>>> valid.group()                                        # Wrong Match
'1'
>>> valid = re.search(r'^\b[1-5]\b$',a)        # Correct Way
>>> valid.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> a = '1'
>>> valid = re.search(r'^\b[1-5]\b$',a)
>>> valid.group()
'1'
>>> a = '1 potato'
>>> valid = re.search(r'^\b[1-5]\b$',a)
>>> valid.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: That will still match inputs such as `1 potato`

Comment: @Kroltan What if I do `valid = re.search(r'^[1-5]$',a)   `

Comment: I could swear that your pre-edit comment had the same regex you used in your answer (`\b[1-5]\b`). But now after your edit, indeed it will work.

Comment: @Kroltan No need of swearing buddy ... Thanks a lot ... Now I will not get any more downvotes also.. Thanks again

Comment: And regarding the edit to your answer: You don't even need the `\b`s anymore, because `^` and `$` will already force matching the whole string. Removed my downvote.

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks for lifting the downvote... But one small problem, some guy has upvoted my answer for mentioning *word boundaries* , so can't edit. I know it is redundant (But can't help) .... *Sorry* buddy (Your answer is indeed the best +1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` (beginning of input) and `$` (end of input) tokens, transforming your regex into:

```
^[1-5]$
```

But for numerical range checking, there's a much simpler solution:

```
theNumber = int(UseInput)
valid = 1 <= theNumber <= 5
```

Or even:

```
theNumber = int(UserInput)
valid = theNumber in range(1,6) #up to six, exclusive, so from 1 to 5 inclusive
```

Comment: `^` is unnecessary since `re.match` is anchored at the start.

Comment: @iCodez True. But I'd still keep it for clarity. (at least for me, I always confuse which of `match` and `search` are anchored)

Answer (score 0):

`re.match` only checks beginning of the string. You could use;

```
valid = re.search('[1-5]',UserInput)
```

Which is checking all over the string.